# Cannot get data from v-for and the data is null

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, api, vue.js

I'm stuck to get the data from the database through Axios using Vue.js. In Vue.js developer tools I can get the data from my database like this:
[image]

But when I loop using `v-for` like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center py-4">
        <NewPost></NewPost>
        <Post v-for="(post,i) in posts.data" :post="post" :key="i"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import NewPost from "../components/NewPost";
import Post from "../components/Post";
export default {
    name: "Newsfeed",
    components: {
        NewPost,
        Post
    },

    data: () => {
        return {
            posts: null
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/posts').then(res => {
            this.posts = res.data
            console.log(this.posts)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Unable to fetch posts')
        })
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The console says

> "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data'
> of null"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/views/Newsfeed.vue
>  at resources/js/components/App.vue
> "

I don't understand because in Vue.js developers tools I can get the data. Is the looping wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init that nested field with an empty array like :

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            posts: {
                   data:[]
                 }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you! I solve too by changing the this.posts = res.data.data and the looping is v-for="post in posts"

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is to add the loading variable like this

In the data :
data: () => {
return {
posts: null,
loading: true
}
}

In the mounted()

```
mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/posts').then(res => {
            this.posts = res.data
            this.loading = false
            console.log(this.posts)
        }).catch(error => {
            this.loading = false
            console.log('Unable to fetch posts')
        })
    }
```